# How to git rm a file containing *

Tags: git, wildcard, rm

As an accident of typing, I've ended up with a file in the repo ending with the `*` character. I'm using Bash.

Let's call the file `"bin/abc*"`. Also there are files `bin/xyz` and others beginning with `bin/abc` such as `bin/abc1` and `bin/abc2`.

I've tried a whole bunch of tactics, including:

1. `$ git rm bin/abc\*`, which deletes all the *other* files, but not the `"bin/abc*"`;
2. `$ git rm bin/abc[*]`, which deletes all the *other* files, but not the `"bin/abc*"`;
3. `$ git rm bin/abc\\*`, which recognises no files;
4. `$ git rm bin/abc[^a-z]`, which recognises no files;
5. `"git rm "bin/abc*"`, which deletes all the *other* files, but not the `"bin/abc*"`;

I've run out of ideas.

Comment: `rm "bin/abc*" && git add bin`

Comment: Reminded me of a typical unix-novice question: how to remove a file named `-rf` using only `rm`? If one cannot run `rm -rf` then what? `rm ./-rf` ! :-)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file is tracked, put the filename in quotes, e.g.

```
git rm "bin/abc*"
```

If it isn't tracked, use `rm` instead of `git rm`:

```
rm "bin/abc*"
```

Comment: Thanks, but alas, no. Same as 1 and 2. Will update my question with this case, however.

Comment: Are you entirely sure that the file is called `bin/abc*`? That should work.

Comment: Is that file _tracked_? `git rm` only operates on tracked files. If it isn't, try just `rm "bin/abc*"`.

Comment: @MattWilson, I've added a second version in case the file isn't tracked. Quoting should definitely work.

Comment: Hi all, yes it is tracked. It's not called "abc*" of course, much longer, but essentially what I've shown indicates properly what's there, i.e. a number of tracked files, all sharing the first part of a steam and all but one of which is normal and one which ends with splat.

Comment: I just did a `git rm *` on the whole directory, then reset and checkout for all the files I _didn't_ want to rm and that way got rid of it. Then I committed, then did a new branch and added back the offending file name, then followed your advice - `git rm "bin/abc*"` - and it works this time. I suspect operator error ...